# WebAPI URI goes wrong

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have created angularjs scripts to call web api. My API config is as below,

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

I am currently in the view `<li>@Html.ActionLink("Create", "GB", "ProjectCreate" , new { area = "" }, null)</li>` and from this page I am calling an api `api/Users/GetUser` but it throws an error that the api is not found and when I check in debug mode, the api being hit is of the uri `ProjectCreate/api/Users/GetUser`.

This is quite weird and I am not getting where the projectcreate appears from here.

Answer (score 0):

it might be the name of your webapplication. Let me know how are you running your app.

Comment: ProjectCreate is the controller name I have but it is not related to my api controller. I am running my app in normal debug mode.

Comment: if possible please share you project or some sample scenario.